# Como exibir os "posts recentes" do WordPress em uma página html externa

Tags: html, wordpress

Fiz um site utilizando HTML & CSS e criei o blog no CMS Wordpress.

Não tenho experiencia com programação e agora preciso buscar no banco de dados os últimos 3 posts recentes do blog que criei.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão por onde devo começar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, não consegui intender muito bem, na próxima coloca mais informação como Theme utilizado etc, bom imagino que você precise adicionar uma nova página ao Wordpress ele trabalha com modelos, dentro da pasta do seu theme geralmente ficam na raiz estes modelos, pegue um copie e dentro podes adicionar o código do Wordpress que lhe trás os últimos posts vide:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

dentro do codex do Wordpress tem muito material bacana.

no seu caso seria algo como:

primeiro crie um template:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

e dentro da página o código que tras os últimos posts:

```
<h2>Titulo Ultimo 3 posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' ); // aqui troca o numero pela quantidade de posts que queira trazer, e caso queira customizar mais o resultado vira aqui dentro do array () veja a pagina.
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .           $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
 ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Joel, irei tentar criar o template.

Comment: @joel-martins, como faço isso com javascript/jquery? Onde quero exibir não aceita php.